# How can I pass object to shadow DOM in a web-component?

Tags: web-component, shadow-dom

currently I'm having trouble using shadow DOM.

What I'm trying to do is, pass function / object to shadow DOM.

The point is, data passing is held on different file.

```
// web-component declaration file

class my-component extends HTMLElement{
   ... all settings set well..
   
   attributeChangedCallback(attrName , oldVal , newVal){
        console.log(newVal) // null
   }
}
```

```
// other file

const x = document.createElement('my-component')
x.customAttribute = [function(){console.log('hi')}]

document.body.appendChild(x)
```

is there anyways passing object to shadow DOM?

Googled , search on youtube ...

Comment: add a custom method on the Web Component class which accepts a (object) parameter

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman thanks for reply, but could we pass function as a attribute to use like event callback function of children node of shadow DOM?

Comment: Sure, its (just) regular JavaScript, so everything is an object, and you can pass everything as String, Objects or whatever

Comment: And no, **attribute** values are Strings only